# adding metadata to filtering in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a generic `ListCreateAPIView` view. I've implemented a `get_queryset` function that performs a search. The function parses the query, extract tags and terms and returns a query set.

```
def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('query', None)

        # No deleted items
        queryset = Items.objects.filter(deleted__isnull=True)

        if query is None:
            return queryset

        predicates = []

        # Generate predicates from query       

        queryset = queryset.filter(reduce(__and__,predicates))
        return queryset
```

**What is the best way to add metadata to the response with data from the `get_queryset` function ?**

I'm looking for something similar to the way pagination works.

```
{
 query : {
     terms : ['term1','term2'], 
     tags  : ['tag1','tag2'] , 
    }
 results : [
      { name : 'item1', .... }
      { name : 'item2', .... }
   ]
}
```

**EDIT**

So i created a custom `FilterBackend` for the filtering and I now have an instance of the request and the response. Looking at the pagination code for django rest i see it's wrapping the results in serializer. The pagination is build into the view class so the fw invokes the serialization if a paginator is detected. Looking at the search api did not produce any new ideas.

My question remains, What is the best, and least intrusive way, of adding metadata from the filter backend to the response ?

One way i can think of (and one that i don't like) is to overload the matadata onto the request in the filter backend and override `finalize_response` in the view - without a doubt the worst way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure it's the best way, but I would probably override `get` to simply intercept the response object and modify response.data however you wish. Something as simple as

```
from rest_framework import generics

class SomeModelList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint representing a list of some things.
    """

    model = SomeModel
    serializer_class = SomeModelSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(SomeModelList, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

        # redefine response.data to include original query params
        response.data = {
            'query': dict(request.QUERY_PARAMS),
            'results': response.data
        }

        return response
```

If you found yourself repeating this for multiple list views you could keep yourself DRY using a Mixin and include it in your list API classes:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.mixins import ListModelMixin

class IncludeQueryListMixin(ListModelMixin):
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(IncludeQueryListMixin, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)

        # redefine response.data to include original query params
        response.data = {
            'query': dict(request.QUERY_PARAMS),
            'results': response.data
        }

        return response


class SomeModelList(IncludeQueryListMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint representing a list of some things.
    """

    model = SomeModel
    serializer_class = SomeModelSerializer
```

Comment: When I tried to intercept the response object I got a "ContentNotRenderedError -- The response content must be rendered before it can be accessed."  Unfortunately, I think that you need to overwrite the places where Response is called so that you can change the format of "data".

Comment: @MarkChackerian I'm not sure what caused your error, but I've updated my answer with full example I verified to work using DRF 2.3.13. Can you re-check?

Comment: I have re-checked and confirmed that your solution works.  I still get the error when I try to inspect the response object, but there isn't actually need to do that.